# iteration burndown chart size not being honored?

Tags: rally

(this is for running reports outside of rally via the loginKey - currently using 1.26, although i have tried using up to 1.32 with no difference in results)

it seems that even though the iteration burndown chart accepts width and height parameters, they are not reliable in any sense, and often not honored at all. if i extract it down to the rendered iframe, i see the following link:

https://loginapirally1.rallydev.com/slm/analytics/reports/4/run?WIDTH=1024&HEIGHT=768&ITERATIONS=[MY_ITERATION]

but the chart is not near that size at all - often it seems to default to a very small size (540pt x 300pt) no matter what w/h is requested. in my implementation, i have the burndown chart in a div that is first adjusted to the size of the window and then those dimensions are passed to the cart object. at some sizes, it will come close to taking up the space, but at others it will revert back to the default size.

is this a known issue? am i missing anything obvious? thanks in advance for any thoughts anybody has!

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason, I have found that the largest I can get most all of the standard reports is Height = 599 and Width = 999. If I go with anything larger, I end up getting back a size much smaller than 599x999. One exception is the Velocity Chart, in which if you have Height of 599 it is large but has a vertical scroll bar, but if you make the height 600 it is smaller and does not have a scroll bar.

Comment: interesting - i do see that does make the biggest chart and it shrinks right back down at 600 or more. i have also contacted rally support and will update this thread with anything they let me know, but thank you very much for this bit of info - much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

i have received confirmation from rally support that indeed this is the max supported resolution when using loginkey:

"Just wanted to let you know that I have received confirmation from our engineering team that the maximum resolution through LoginKey is indeed 600x1000, so the 599x999 would indeed be correct."